# JSON Schema Parsing to get column names as per the schema order

Tags: json, scala, parsing, schema

I extracting the fields from the Json schema(properties) but the fields are not as per schema order.

Code:-
JSon Schema file-

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": [ "title", "description" ],
  "properties": {
    "title": { "type": "string" },
    "description": { "type": "string" },
    "termsOfServiceUrl": { "type": "string", "format": "uri" },
    "contact": { "type": "integer", "format": "email" },
    "license": { "type": "string" },
    "licenseUrl": { "type": "string", "format": "uri" }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}

val schemafileparse = parse(schemafile)

 val column_list = (schemafileparse \"properties").camelizeKeys.extract[Map[String,Any]].keySet
```

Results:-

```
Set(termsOfServiceUrl, description, contact, license, title, licenseUrl)
```

Expected results:-

```
Set(title, description, termsOfServiceUrl, contact, license, licenseUrl)
```

how can i get the expected results. I will get the data file separately as per json config schema.

Answer (score 0):

Since [JObject](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/67f89be9c60adeb671f61f1353764b1edf23316e/ast/src/main/scala/org/json4s/JsonAST.scala#L153) is defaulting using the `HashMap` to get the **JObject** values, and the **HashMap** is **unordered**.

So maybe you can manually to collect field name from `JObject`, like:

```
  val column_list = (schemafileparse \ "properties") match {
    case JObject(k) => k.map(i => i._1)
  }
```